# Penalties involved in withholding knowledge of a rule violation

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Player 1 won Game 1, Player 2 won Game 2, and it is at some point during Game 3 now. In Game 2, P2's [Venser, Sojourner](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=212240) exiled a number of P1's cards and P1 doesn't remember the exiled cards when presenting his deck to P2 for Game 3, but P2 did notice but did not notify P1.

As the game progresses, P2 realizes he is losing and then calls a judge, telling him or her that P1's deck is illegal as it is under 60 cards. It should be mentioned that P2 knew the deck was illegal and withheld this information until it was opportune for him or her.

What are the specific rule violations on both players, specifically P2? Does it change if P2 did not know the deck was illegal and only just noticed it? Just curious if P2's failure to notify P1 of their illegal deck changes the penalty for P1.

Comment: How is it inopportune to report your opponent's illegal deck right away? This is important for answering the question.

Comment: @Hackworth maybe P2 is unsure of what a judge will do. Maybe a judge would give P1 some lenience the earlier it is caught.

Comment: @Hackworth I'm not very familiar with tournament rules, but I would think that if a deck were discovered to be missing a few cards during the initial shuffling, before any game play had begun, then a judge would just tell you to put the cards back before starting the game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Player 1 would be committing a Tournament Error (Deck/Decklist Problem) under item 1 of section 3.9 of the [IPG](https://www.wizards.com/ContentResources/Wizards/WPN/Main/Documents/Magic_The_Gathering_Infraction_Procedure_Guide_PDF2.pdf):

> The deck and/or decklist contain an illegal number
>    of cards for the format.

If decklists are registered, it's also a violation of item 4:

> The contents of the presented deck and sideboard do not match the decklist registered.

The penalty for this is a game loss.

Player 2 would be Cheating under section 4.8, which a player commits if he or she "notices an offense committed in his or her (or a teammate's) match and does not call attention to it", if these two conditions are met:

> - The player must be attempting to gain advantage from his or her action.
> - The player must be aware that he or she is doing something illegal.

The penalty for this is disqualification.

Player 2 might also be committing a Game Play Error under section 2.6, which is defined like this:

> A player allows another player in the game to commit a Game Play Error involving an effect or action that he or she does not control, and has not pointed it out immediately.

Player 1 would have to be committing a Game Play Error for this to apply. Section 2.5, which defines Game Rule Violation, "handles violations of the Comprehensive Rules that are not covered by the other Game Play Errors". A Tournament Error is not a violation of the comprehensive rules, but the comprehensive rules do say this:

> 100.2a In constructed play (a way of playing in which each player creates his or her own deck ahead of time), each deck must contain at least sixty cards
>   Even if this means sections 2.5 and 2.6 apply, the penalties for both are less than the penalties for violations under sections 3.9 and 4.8. Also, the IPG suggests using the latter two in this case:
>
> If a judge believes a player is intentionally not pointing out 
>   other players’ illegal actions, either for his or her own advantage, or in the hope of bringing it up at a more 
>   strategically advantageous time, they should consider an Unsporting Conduct — Cheating infraction.

Comment: The question asked, "What are the specific rule violations for **both** players?" This answer only covers P2.

Comment: Is P2 doing anything illegal though? You would also need to quote a rule that says that players are required to point out a violation by their opponent.

Comment: @GendoIkari From a slightly different section (2.6) of the rules: "If a judge believes a player is intentionally not pointing out other players’ illegal actions, either for his or her own advantage, or in the hope of bringing it up at a more strategically advantageous time, they should consider an Unsporting Conduct — Cheating infraction."

Comment: Also, the immediately preceding text in section 4.8 reads: "A person breaks a rule defined by the tournament documents, lies to a tournament official, **or notices an offense committed in his or her (or a teammate's) match and does not call attention to it.**" (emphasis mine)

Comment: In a situation where P1 is awarded a game loss and P2 is disqualified, is P2 actually awarded a game win? Not sure how this scenario affects ranking at sanctioned play.